# Breaking POCO relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

I'm experiencing a problem in breaking a relationship bteween two entities. Let's say we have a `Child` entity which belongs to one `Parent`, a `Parent` has many `Child` entities. Now in my front end a user can select a radio button to choose which `Parent` the `Child` belongs to or they can choose "None". The trouble I'm having is that when I edit a `Child` record and select "None", it doesn't seem to break an existing relationship.

In my business logic I am doing the following:

```
child.Parent = parentRepository.Find(command.ParentID);
```

The repository method returns null if no record matches the passed in ID, and selecting "None" gives an ID of 0 yet when I debug and step over this line, Child.Parent still has a reference to the previously chosen Parent entity. In fact, even explicitly setting Child.Parent = null; doesn't seem to break the link.

To add to my confusion, this isn't consistant behaviour. Every now and then the same code *does* break the relationship and set Child.Parent to null! Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I updated my code to ensure that the repo is returning null.

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.Find(command.ParentID);
if (parent == null)
    child.parent = null;
else
    child.parent = parent;
```

Debugging shows that the line `child.parent = null;` *is* being executed, yet when I check `child.parent` after this line, it still shows a reference to the previously referenced `Parent` object. But every now and then, it is correctly setting to null. This version works:

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.Find(command.ParentID);
if (parent == null)
{
    child.parent = null;
    child.parent = null;
}
else
    child.parent = parent;
```

Why do I have to set it to null twice to get consistant behaviour? Do I have to explicitly declare that `Parent` is nullable on the `Child` entity somehow?

Comment: Paste in the child model code too. If you are doing any fluent API calls in the OnModelCreating event, show them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to declare that the parent is nullable.

If you expose a foreign key property on the child, it has to be nullable. So if your child has a ParentId property, it should look like this:

```
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
public virtual Parent { get; set; }
```

If you are using the fluent API, you can tell EF that the parent is nullable like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>.HasOptional(d => d.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children);
```

Or like this, if you declare the relationship from the principal end rather than the dependent end:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>.HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOptional(d => d.Parent);
```

It is strange that the child.Parent needs to be set to null twice. Have you tried stepping into the code to see why? You could also try this for your Parent property, to see exactly what is going on:

```
private Parent _parent;
public virtual Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
    set { _parent = value; }
}
```

This is code you can actually step into, to make sure that the private field is being set to null.

**Response to comment**

It does sound like there is an issue with lazy loading going on. Try this.

In your repository Find method, eager load the parent. You can do that with something like this:

```
context.Children.Include(c => c.Parent).Find(id);
```

This would make child.Parent already loaded on the context, and setting to null once should suffice.

Comment: Ok so I changed the Parent property as suggested to see what is happening. When the set is called, _parent is null and it remains null until I hovver the cursor over the public virtual Parent! It then hydrates, at which point I can successfully set it to null. If I dont hovver over, it remains null, like its not pulled the record back from the db so when I set it to null, it does nothing. Is this some sort of lazy loading going on? I would have thought that when I call child.parent, EF would hydrate the Parent?

Comment: Looks like the behaviour I am getting is normal. Because the Parent navigation property is virtual, lazy loading applies. It appears that on first call to the navigation property, the related object is hydrated from the db. So when I am setting it to null with child.parent = null; all the code is really doing is getting the record from the db. Hence why the second child.parent = null; attempt works. Anyway, thanks for the answer, its really helped me figure this out.